# How to create multiple objects in a single main object in JSON?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, xcode, object

I have 3 arrays which i want to convert in multiple objects:

```
NSArray *finalJSONArray = @[@"0",@"3",@"6",@"8"];
NSArray *time = @[@"12am",@"1am",@"2am",@"3am"];
NSArray *time = @[@"Sunday",@"Monday",@"Tuesday",@"Wednesday",@"Thursday"];
```

and now i want to convert these two arrays in jSON string like this:

```
{
"Sunday": {
    "0": "12 AM",
    "3": "1 AM",
    "6": "2 AM",
    "8": "3 AM"
},
"Monday": {
    "0": "12 AM",
    "3": "1 AM",
    "6": "2 AM",
    "8": "3 AM"
},
"Tuesday": {
    "0": "12 AM",
    "3": "1 AM",
    "6": "2 AM",
    "8": "3 AM"
},
"Wednesday": {
    "0": "12 AM",
    "3": "1 AM",
    "6": "2 AM",
    "8": "3 AM"
},
"Thursday": {
    "0": "12 AM",
    "3": "1 AM",
    "6": "2 AM",
    "8": "3 AM"
}
}
```

here is my code right now without populated, i tried different methods to populate these NSDictionaries but can't get the same result:

```
// Empty array
NSDictionary *emptyArray = @{};

// Single element array
NSDictionary *singleElementArray = @{};

// Array of above arrays
NSArray *arrayOfObjects = @[emptyArray, singleElementArray];

// Dictionary with several kay/value pairs and the above array of arrays
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"Sunday" : arrayOfObjects};

NSError *error = nil;
NSData *json;

// Dictionary convertable to JSON ?
if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:dict])
{
    // Serialize the dictionary
    json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

    // If no errors, let's view the JSON
    if (json != nil && error == nil)
    {
        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:json encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", jsonString);
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems to me like you're doing something crazy or dealing with something already done in a crazy way. Pretty sure this task should be implemented in an easier way

Comment: @AndreyChernukha yes i am using this code:

http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/ios-and-json-part-1-serialize-objects-to-json.html

Comment: are the `"0" : "12 AM", "3" : "1 AM", "6" : "2 AM", and "8" : "3 AM"` pairs fixed ?

Comment: @RicetongTan OK let's say if they are fix... i just want syntax, i can create logic my self... basically it's a data of whole day hours ... i just posted a little amount of it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you populate your dictionary in the structure that you wanted:

```
NSArray *finalJSONArray = @[@"0",@"3",@"6",@"8"];
NSArray *timeArray      = @[@"12am",@"1am",@"2am",@"3am"];
NSArray *dayArray       = @[@"Sunday",@"Monday",@"Tuesday",@"Wednesday",@"Thursday"];

NSMutableDictionary *resultDic = [@{} mutableCopy];
for (NSString *day in dayArray)
{
    resultDic[day] = [@{} mutableCopy];

    NSUInteger numOfObjects = MIN([finalJSONArray count], [timeArray count]);
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfObjects; i++)
    {
        resultDic[day][finalJSONArray[i]] = timeArray[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Say that the `"0" : "12 AM", "3" : "1 AM", "6" : "2 AM", and "8" : "3 AM"` pairs are fixed, the following will create the NSDictionary which you could convert into the JSON of the format you want:

```
NSDictionary *hoursDict = @{@"0" : @"12am",
                            @"3" : @"1am",
                            @"6" : @"2am",
                            @"8" : @"3am"};

NSDictionary *hoursForDaysDict = @{@"Sunday" : hoursDict,
                                   @"Monday" : hoursDict,
                                   @"Tuesday" : hoursDict,
                                   @"Wednesday" : hoursDict,
                                   @"Thursday" : hoursDict};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

say you have 3 arrays

```
NSArray *values = @[@"0",@"3",@"6",@"8"];
NSArray *times = @[@"12am",@"1am",@"2am",@"3am"];
NSArray *days = @[@"Sunday",@"Monday",@"Tuesday",@"Wednesday",@"Thursday"];
```

then

```
NSMutableDictionary *finalDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for(NSString *day in days) {

    NSMutableArray *valuePairArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSInteger count = 0;
    for (NSString *value in values) {

        if ([times count] > count) {

            NSDictionary *dataDict = @{value: times[count]};
            [valuePairArray addObject:dataDict];

        }
        count++;
    }
    [finalDict setObject:valuePairArray forKey:day];
}

NSLog(@"%@", finalDict);
```

now convert this dictionary to JSON